# Polymer communication between elements

Tags: data-binding, polymer, two-way

I want to achieve communication between child parent with Polymer element.

Here my index.html

```
<proto-receiver data="message">
        <proto-element data="message"></proto-element>
</proto-receiver>
```

Both element have their respective "data" property

```
properties: {
   data: {
      value: 'my-data',
      notify: true,
   }
},
```

In proto-receiver, which is the parent I update "data" by handling simple click

```
<template>
    <span on-tap="onClick">proto receiver: {{data}}</span>
    <content></content>
</template> 


onClick: function () {
    this.data = 'new-message';
},
```

I want the change to be propagate to the child element as well, as it mentioned [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#property-notification).

I achieve this by passing a setter in my child element and called it like this. Which is, I guess, not the way it should be done.

```
 Polymer.Base.$$('body').querySelector('proto-element').setData(this.data);
```

What I'm doing wrong

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

For those coming here. The proper way of doing this is by using Events.

[Polymer 1.x](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events)

```
this.fire('kick', {kicked: true});
```

[Polymer 2.x](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/events) (simple javascript)

```
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('kick', {detail: {kicked: true}}));
```

In both case the receiver should implement the regular addEventListener

```
document.querySelector('x-custom').addEventListener('kick', function (e) {
    console.log(e.detail.kicked); // true
})
```

Comment: Probably you want `Polymer.dom(this).querySelector('proto-element').setData(this.data);`. However, if your `proto-*` objects are themselves inside a Polymer template, you can use data-binding to do this for you.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Did you mean that the change are not propagate due to the <content></content> tag? Effectively putting my child element directly inside the parent Polymer template work just fine. Seems that the same problem are mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369519/bind-data-to-content-element-in-polymer)

Comment: `<content>` changes the _rendering_ context but it doesn't change the actual tree relationships. In your example, `proto-element` remains a direct child of `proto-receiver` regardless of `<content>`. What I meant above was that if both elements are themselves in a template, you can bind them directly: `<template><p-r data="{{data}}"><p-e data="{{data}}"></p-e></p-r></template>`

Answer (score 4):

To provide a concrete example to [Scott Miles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2192324/scott-miles)' comments, if you can wrap your parent and child elements in a Polymer template (such as `dom-bind` or as children to yet another Polymer element), then you can handle this declaratively. Check out the [mediator pattern](https://youtu.be/ZDjiUmx51y8?list=PLNYkxOF6rcICdISJclfQhj2S8QZGjXV8J&t=630).

parent element:

```
<dom-module id="parent-el">
  <template>
    <button on-tap="onTap">set message from parent-el</button>
    <p>parent-el.message: {{message}}</p>
    <content></content>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'parent-el',
      properties: {
        message: {
          type: String,
          notify: true
        }
      },
      onTap: function() {
        this.message = 'this was set from parent-el';
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

child element:

```
<dom-module id="child-el">
  <template>
    <p>child-el.message: {{message}}</p>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'child-el',
      properties: {
        message: {
          type: String,
          notify: true
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

`index.html`:

```
<template is="dom-bind" id="app">
  <parent-el message="{{message}}">
    <child-el message="{{message}}"></child-el>
  </parent-el>
</template>
<script>
  (function(document) {
    var app = document.querySelector('#app');
    app.message = 'this was set from index.html script';
  }) (document);
</script>
```

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/sesula/3/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same issue and got solution for it and fixed it as below

```
this.fire('iron-signal', {name: 'hello', data: null});
```

You can refer this iron-signals you will get the solution which you are looking for its basically event fire from any element to another

Hope this will help you
[Polymer iron signals](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-signals/elements/iron-signals)

Comment: It might be good to add that the fire event can also be used to fire up more then one Element.