# With regards to Polymer, How do I get one web component to 'speak' to another web component?

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, polymer, web-component

I want to be able to fill out a form in web component 1, click a submit button in web component 1 and then post that data to a grid in web component 2. Web component 1 is in a different html file then web component 2.

```
//web component 1
<dom module id="foo-form">
<template>
  <paper-input id="myID" label="ID"value="{{myID}}"></paper-input>
  <paper-button id="submitForm" on-click="submitForm">Submit</paper-button>
</template>
 <script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";
  Polymer({
    is: 'foo-form',
     });
    })();
 </script>
</dom-module>


//Web component 2*
<dom-module id="my-grid">
  <template>
    <vaadin-grid selection-mode="single" id="fooBarGrid" >
      <table>
        <col name="vendorID" sortable="" />
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
         </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </vaadin-grid>
  </template>
 <script>
   document.addEventListener("WebComponentsReady", function() {

      // Reference to the grid element.
      var grid = grid || document.querySelector("#fooBarGrid");

      // Reference to the template element
      var template = template || document.querySelector("template");

      // Add some example data as an array.
      var data = [
        { "myId": 0 } 
      ];
      grid.items = data;
 });

  </script>
 <script>
    (function() {
      'use strict';

      Polymer({
          is: 'my-grid',
        });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two ways to do it:

1. Use the [mediator pattern](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDjiUmx51y8&feature=youtu.be&list=PLNYkxOF6rcICdISJclfQhj2S8QZGjXV8J&t=630). This works well if you have a parent element that contains both your `my-grid` and `foo-form` element. A solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35463667/polymer-communication-between-elements)
2. If you want to communicate between elements that don't have a common parent or different DOM branches, you can use [iron-signals](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-signals) which provies basic publish and subscribe functionality.

Solution 1 is the recommended approach.